# How to run sbt-revolver with a Scala project?

Tags: scala, sbt, spray, akka-http, sbt-revolver

So I'm reading the documentation for sbt-revolver since I'm interest in using its:

> Triggered restart: automatically restart your application as soon as some of its sources have been changed

It says in the documentation that it should work with any scala project ( I'm running an Akka Http) as long as it has a class with a main method and that we just need to plug in `project/plugins.sbt`:

`addSbtPlugin("io.spray" % "sbt-revolver" % "0.9.0")`

So I did that then I went with terminal to root folder, ran `sbt` wait it to load and then  `run`, now I made a small change in some file that loads and html with some `<h1>` but changes aren't reloaded, what am I missing?

## Update

So after running `sbt` in terminal, then I run `~reStart` and it seems to exit the server:

```
root Server online at localhost:8080 root Press RETURN to stop... root ... 
finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options, if you need only `run`, no need the revolver plugin, just start it with

```
~run
```

If you need revolver, you should use

```
~reStart
```

as it is stated on their homepage too:

> You can use `~reStart` to go into "triggered restart" mode. Your application starts up and SBT watches for changes in your source (or resource) files. If a change is detected SBT recompiles the required classes and sbt-revolver automatically restarts your application.

Note, you can specify any command to be run [on each change of source files](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Running-Commands.html) after `~`.

Comment: so after running `sbt` in terminal then I run `~reStart` and it seems to exit the server: root Server online at http://localhost:8080/
root Press RETURN to stop...
root ... finished with exit code 0

Comment: In case you are using Scala both on client and server, for client changes, you might prefer Li Haoyi's [Workbench](https://github.com/lihaoyi/workbench).